# Persistence diagram feels wrong...?

Tags: python, plotly, persistence, analysis, diagram

[image]

This is an image of my python plotly diagram, I feel like it looks wrong but somebody ensured that based on a chart this is technically correctly plotted?

In a sense, this is based off the Nasdaq chart from the previous year:

[image]

But my persistence diagram doesn't look like a normal persistent homology graph?

I'm really not sure what the actual problem is as this is more a question whether it looks correct based on the nasdaq chart? Or if I'm just way off. Also an example of a recent persistence diagram based on the previous nasdaq yearly data would be great thanks.

Edit: the reason I say this is because this is normally what persistence diagram looks like:

[image]

Thanks in advance (P.S. I'm new to stackoverflow sorry if this isn't very specific to programming but it is python I guess..?)